# Vue allows for only a single page web app in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js, single-page-application

Is there a way to create a web app with multiple pages using Spring Boot and Vue.js?

I used to work with Laravel which allows the use of vue components in blade files which is why I found it weird that all of the tutorials that I have found about Spring Boot and Vue.js were only directed to creating single page applications.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Vue and Spring are two very different frameworks; they should both have independent projects and work together through REST controllers on Spring's side, and a store in Vue's side. You can use Vue without an SPA context, but it will be very limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, I don't support having the background framework rely on a front-end framework or vice versa. These must be two separate entities. **See microservice architecure.** Of course, multiple Vue projects can use the same server, thus implementing the "two-sided" principle. From now on, we can also expand to multi-browser (more Vue or Angular projects) and mobile platforms, which are served by a specific server via API interfaces.

Spring has security, filtering modules that you use some logic to determine if project "A" can call a particular endpoint, but project "B" can no longer and will get forbidden. *Or you can even put in a separate API Gateway for that purpose with Nginx or Spring Gateway before API.*

For example, you can implement an application token that accepts or deny on the server-side.

Broadly just a theoretical model. You can do this better, of course.
[image]